# How to refresh the list to get new data from service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to call web service, receive data from that and display in the list. I am using directives.

- When my fiddle load I load data from `JSON`. Which is working fine.I am able to load data.
- Then I click **delete** button my list is empty.In other words I removed all item from the list.Which is working fine
- Now when I click on **refresh** button I need to call service again and get the fresh data from  service.

But it is not showing in list why?
Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/8fjhLqnw/10/

```
.controller('he', function($http, $scope, sharedData) {
    var h = this;

    h.referesh=function(){
        sharedData.get();
    }
    h.delete = function() {
        sharedData.delete()
    }
});
```

Update see plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/iMpStNneDmIsabTnFqpP?p=preview

I need simply that on click of refresh button I want to load data of **data.json** and display on list form

Comment: is `referesh` a typo? in `h.referesh = `

Comment: Mean I need to call service again as I did first time .when fiddle load

Comment: mean when it call the service again and get the fresh data from server..currently fresh data is same as previous data

Comment: when I click refresh I need to call get request to load json file and display in list

Comment: `Location.reload(true)` ? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: it is not good way...I need to call $http request to fetch data from server

Comment: Either that or use a XMLHttpRequest and resend the request that asks for the information

Comment: @user944513 What is the purpose of the `sharedData` service? Is it to fetch data and display it on the view? Or do you expect the `sharedData` service to fetch data and update all views referencing the data?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I take sharedData because to communicate between the directives..mean I need to share some data between directive..

Comment: is there any other way because my buttons are on header directive and list is another directive

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/iMpStNneDmIsabTnFqpP?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fjhLqnw/11/)

The problem is you are refreshing the reference to sharedData.data in your refresh call. The f controller binds itself to sharedData.data (i.e. vm.data = sharedData.data) at the time before the data is refreshed, and that vm.data reference is never updated (always points to the original deleted array). To fix, build a reference to sharedData itself and access the data property inside from the template:

```
// continued off module definition
.directive('tm', function() {

    // reference vm.sharedData.data in the template
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="n in vm.sharedData.data">{{n.name}}</li></ul></div>',
        scope: {},
        controller: 'f',
        controllerAs: 'vm'

    };
}).controller('f', function($http, $scope, sharedData) {
    var vm = this;
    // initialize shared data
    sharedData.get().then(function(){
    vm.sharedData = sharedData;
    });
```

When the data is refreshed, the data property of sharedData will reset and will be picked up by the template because the scope references sharedData reference (which does not change). The template will see any changes inside sharedData (data property that is refreshed).